# Query not invalidated correctly in react-query

Tags: react-query

I am doing a mutation with the `useMutation` hook of React-Query. Inside the `onSuccess` callback, I am calling `queryClient.invalidateQueries(['key'])` to invalidate another query. That other query gets called again but the data is incorrect (it should be updated). I took a look at the Network tab and seems like the second query is made before the first one succeeds as you can see in the following image:
[image]

In the backend, I put a sleep function to wait before sending the response of the second query. It worked and the second query actually returned the correct data, meaning there is some kind of race condition just because the second query is not sent after the first one succeeds.

When I use `onSettled`, the query is made after the first one, but I want to use `onSuccess` because `onSettled` also fires when there is an error.

Comment: Can you show the code related to this question?

Comment: seems like the backend returns from the update endpoint before it actually finishes writing to the database? onSuccess and onSettled run directly after each other so there's no difference (for this case) to when you call the invalidation

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. I was not returning a `Promise` in the `queryFn` function of react-query, so React Query couldn't resolve it and know when the first query finished.